# Django tests: Test that a certain number of elements appear in page?

Tags: django

I'm working in Django 1.8. I'd like to test that there are four `<li>` elements in my page.

This is my existing `test_views.py`:

```
def test_call_view_bnf_all(self):
    response = self.client.get('/bnf/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    context_sections = response.context['sections']
    self.assertEqual(len(context_sections), 4)

    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'all_bnf.html')
    self.assertContains(response, '<h1>All BNF sections</h1>')
```

How can I test that there are four `<li>` elements in the page, short of providing all the raw HTML and doing an `assertContains`?

Answer (score 1):

[`assertContains()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertContains) has a `count` option built in:

> ```
> assertContains(response, text, count=None, status_code=200, msg_prefix='', html=False)
> ```
>
> If **count** is provided, **text** must occur exactly **count** times in the response.

Therefore, you can use:

```
self.assertContains(response, '</li>', 4)
```

Comment: @JLPeyret, yep! No external dependencies required. However, using something else like lxml, BeautifulSoup, or your recommendation of PyQuery would be a better option if a lot of html parsing needs to be done. By the way, thanks for sharing that library. I've never heard of it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to achieve this. Something along the lines of:

```
def test_call_view_bnf_all(self):
    response = self.client.get('/bnf/')
    response_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    li_elements = response_soup.find_all('li')
    self.assertEqual(len(li_elements), 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [PyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) to do this kind of stuff.  Basically, you'd end up writing a jquery selector and then testing the result.  The nice thing, being jquery-compatible is that you can test your selector in your browser first.

Pretty happy with PyQuery so far, except that it has an lxml dependency which I have found is challenging to install with Chef.

```
data = PyQuery(response.content)
result = data("li")

#haven't used PyQuery to check the length of a result yet
#might be
self.assertEqual(4,len(result))
```